# Azure Storage SDK - check if Blob is directory in hierarchical storage

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-storage

I have an Azure Storage Account with hierarchical storage turned on. I'm getting a list of blobs in a container and trying to figure whether or not a particular blob is a directory.

I have it working in a REST API client like this:

```
public async Task<List<StoragePath>> ListPathsAsync(string filesystem)
{
    string uri = $"https://{accountName}.{dnsSuffix}/{filesystem}?recursive=true&resource=filesystem";
    var result = await SendRequestAsync<StoragePathList>(HttpMethod.Get, uri, CancellationToken.None, true);
    return result.Content.Paths?.ToList();
}

public class StoragePath
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isDirectory")]
    public bool IsDirectory { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

The `SendRequestAsync<T>` method just uses JsonConvert to deserialize the content of the API response.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing using the .net SDK but I don't see the IsDirectory property anywhere.

```
public async Task<List<StoragePath>> ListPathsAsync(string filesystem)
    {
        var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, filesystem);
        var list = new List<StoragePath>();
        var enumerator = containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync().GetAsyncEnumerator();

        while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            var current = enumerator.Current;
            list.Add(new StoragePath()
            {
                Name = current.Blob.Name,
                //IsDirectory = current.Blob.Properties.
            });
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Is there some other property I should be checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I returned to this question months later using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0`. The `CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(....)` method returns a collection of `IListBlobItem`. You can determine whether each one is a directory by checking its concrete type.

I have a model class like this:

```
public class StoragePath
{
    public bool IsDirectory { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can populate the values using an Automapper profile as follows:

```
public class StorageProfile : Profile
{
    public StorageProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<IListBlobItem, StoragePath>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.IsDirectory, prop => prop.MapFrom(src => src is CloudBlobDirectory))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, prop => prop.MapFrom(src => GetName(src)));
    }

    private string GetName(IListBlobItem src)
    {
        switch (src)
        {
            case CloudBlobDirectory dir:
                return dir.Prefix;
            case CloudBlob blob:
                return blob.Name;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @connell-odonnell my apologies, this question is almost 3 years old but I'm wondering how you use this in an application. Because although the constructor has the mapper inside, how do you tell the mapper to convert IListBlobItem to StoragePath? Is it correct if you do something like this somewhere in your code: var storagePath = Mapper.Map<IListBlobItem, StoragePath>(listBlobItem)?

Answer (score 1):

Just as explained in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#blob-names):

> The Blob service is based on a flat storage scheme, not a hierarchical
>   scheme. However, you may specify a character or string delimiter
>   within a blob name to create a virtual hierarchy.

However, with [.NET Azure Storage SDK(v12)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet), the `blobContainerClient.GetBlobs()` method will just directly return the blob with full path.

[image]

However, with [.NET Azure Storage SDK(v11)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet-legacy), it will only retrieve the next-level directories and blobs:

[image]

So, you can use v11 SDK, and manually check if the item is a directory or blob.

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

foreach(var item in cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Uri);
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
    {
        CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;
        Console.WriteLine("A directory, prefix is : " + directory.Prefix);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something a bit less hackey than using a directory prefix but if this is a limitation of the API then so be it. Thanks for the help.